# Unable to override the JAVA home in openSUSE 13.1

Tags: bash, java, path

What I did: made an entry in both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin
```

Still the system points to some openJDK installed by default. 
Found by issuing `java-version`.

So what can be done in this case?

Comment: Tried `. ~/bash_profile` and the same with ~/.profile ?

Comment: You should use quotes in the `export PATH` command: ``export PATH="$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenJDK version is being found first on your PATH.  You can verify which one is being invoked by running

```
>which java
```

Try changing "export PATH" to put your new JDK first instead of last, like this:

```
>export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:$PATH
```

Start a new shell and then try "which java" or "java -version" - you should now get your new version.

Comment: you are just awesome. This Worked !

Comment: You should use quotes in the `export PATH` command: ``export PATH="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:$PATH"``.